Monitoring Remote Login Attempts on Windows 8 via Event Viewer
We are using a test PC called pc-test, running Windows 8 (Version 6.3, Build 9600). Multiple users have access to this machine, but at any given time, only one user can connect. We have enabled Remote Desktop Connection on this PC.
Here’s the situation:
When a user (e.g., abc) is logged into the test PC, and another user (e.g., xyz) unknowingly tries to access it, a prompt appears on user abc's screen stating:

Another user is currently logged on to this computer. If you continue, this user has to disconnect from this computer. Do you want to continue?

This prompt gives 30 seconds to either allow or deny the connection.
We want to monitor how many times users attempt to log in to the pc-test while it is in use.
Specifically, we are looking for:

Is there any Event ID that logs when this prompt is generated in abc user's PC?
If no specific Event ID exists for this prompt, what is the best method to monitor login attempts to the same PC, especially when another user is already logged in?

This is because we are having a requirement to log such cases and get the count of occurrences where this prompt is shown. We would like this prompt to be there, so disabling the prompt and allowing other user to directly connect by disconnecting the former user's session is not an option.
We have already reviewed the Event Viewer logs, but it is unclear whether this specific login attempt (with the prompt) is being recorded.
List of event IDs we checked : 4624,4625,4634 in Microsoft windows security.
Any help or guidance on which Event IDs to monitor or alternative methods for tracking these login attempts would be greatly appreciated!

You can search the Event Log yourself for that answer. To make it easier, there are tools such as Nirsoft's free FullEventLogView and others that enable searching all of the numerous Event Logs in a single, flattened, view, rather than the hierarchical presentation of the Windows utility.


Using FullEventLogView, press F9 to show the Advanced Options dialog.
Select an appropriate time period.
Select all Event Levels.
Click OK to apply changes.
Have someone connect to the PC.
Refresh the list of events by pressing F5 and look for new events associated with that connection.

